# Application rejected when try to deploy it on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am, following this tutorial https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 when i run this command git push heroku master i am getting the following error.can any one please help how to remove this error.

ritesh@ritesh-desktop:~/rails_projects/myapp$ git push heroku master

```
Counting objects: 63, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (63/63), 25.89 KiB, done.
Total 63 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.0.pre.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/ --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Installing rake (10.0.3)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.5.0)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.3)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.3)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.1)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.1)
       Installing tilt (1.3.3)
       Installing sprockets (2.1.3)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.3)
       Installing mime-types (1.19)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.12)
       Installing mail (2.4.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.3)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.35)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.3)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.3)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.2)
       Installing json (1.7.5)
       Installing rdoc (3.12)
       Installing thor (0.14.6)
       Installing railties (3.2.3)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (2.1.4)
       Using bundler (1.3.0.pre.2)
       Installing rails (3.2.3)
       Installing sass (3.2.4)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.5)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.6)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_o15pfc3jol9k/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_o15pfc3jol9k/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.6/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.6'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:sheltered-hollows-2496.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sheltered-hollows-2496.git
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Veraticus says, Heroku does not support SQLite databases. If you'd like to continue to use SQLite for developing, in your Gemfile, you can add the following lines around `gem sqlite3`:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Heroku doesn't install gems that are only used for development (per the `bundle install --without development:test` part of the stacktrace), so it won't try to install the sqlite3 gem, and you can continue to use it for development.

(As an aside, you may also have to require the pg gem in production to make things work with Heroku's postgres database, which you can do like so:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot push a project that uses the sqlite3 gem to Heroku -- they do not support sqlite3 databases. You must either use [Heroku's Postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) or your own database solution that your application can connect to outside of Heroku.